# How to add header link in magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, toplinks

I want to add header links in magento Blank Theme

Default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="top.links">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="new.link" after="register-link">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="false">New Link</argument>
            <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="false">newlink</argument>
        </arguments>
      </block>
 </referenceBlock>
```

i have added **top.links** because its blank theme.
after that i ran all **CLI** command. but link is not displaying on frontend.

Answer (score 1):

**Add top link with frontend theme:**

> 1. app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
  'frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Theme Title</title>
    <parent>[VendorName]/[themename]</parent> <!-- Magento/blank OR Magento/luma -->
</theme>
```

> 3. app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[themename]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

If you've extended Luma Theme:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="header-new-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new-link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you've extended Blank Theme:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link" name="header-new-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">New Link</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true">new-link</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

> 4. Magento CLI

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: You can follow this link. It may help you https://rishabhrkrai.wordpress.com/2016/10/19/add-home-link-on-top-menu/

Comment: @Pratik Oza thanks for your reply ..i have fallowed above but its not working for me.

Comment: @Pratic Oza Thanks for reply. i have fallowed same but that time i did not get link on header. but now i am getting header link on top.

Comment: @ErSarveshVTiwari - Glad to help you :)

Comment: @Pratik Oza Can you also help me how to add footer link